# Couldn't configure timezone for log4j console appender

Tags: java, log4j

I am trying to configure my application (which uses log4j as a logging mechanism) to log the messages with `UTC-08:00` time but it is throwing errors when log4j is initialized and the messages are continued to be logged with system time. I am not sure whether the parameter `TimeZone` is not acceptable for the layout `PatterLayout`. Could anyone please help me figure out what I am doing wrong here?

Log4J Configuration:

```
<appender name="CustomAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{MM:dd:yyyy HH:mm:ss} %m%n" />
        <param name="TimeZone" value="UTC-08:00" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<root>
    <priority value="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="CustomAppender" />
</root>
```

The warning message shown when initializing the log4j is,

```
log4j:WARN No such property [timeZone] in org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timezone is set inside the value of ConversionPattern.

Details: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/EnhancedPatternLayout.html

Answer (score 0):

The following is the log4j configuration that I have used for converting the time to particular time zone. I have added this answer for my future reference.

Log4J Configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="CustomAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{DATE}{IST} IST %-5p [%t] %c: %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="CustomAppender" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

The string `{IST}` in the conversion pattern above will convert the time to Indian Standard Time and the another string `IST` will be added in the logger message (this is optional).

You can use any valid `ISO-8601` timezone in the conversion pattern - either a named timezone like `IST` or with offsets like `UTC+05:30`